# Make vb.net app capable of running on any PC with .net installed

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

For example, if I create an application with .net 2.0 dependency and I try to run it on a PC with .net 4.5, it doesn't work. (It says I have to install .net 2.0 and 3.5)

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this instruction on MSDN how to set `<supportedRuntime>` in your `app.config` file.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In your case add `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>` in your `app.config`