# How Targetting Multi .NETFrameworks?

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config, visual-studio-2019

I saw several tutorials on web where basically is suggested Edit/Create an *app.config* file and use `<supportedRuntime>` tag to make the application run in any version of .NET Frameworks listed on file (since that some version is installed on target machine). Then i tried reproduce this same approach but without sucess, for example if i define target .net framework to **4.0** on project creation and define on *.config* file to also support othees versions, is request to install **4.0** version in any machine that still not had installed (for example in a machine only with v**1.0**/v**2.0**/v**3.5**), in others words, seems that settings on *app.config* are ignored even that my file seems like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" sku="Client"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Some idea about how prevent these behavior?

---

References:

1. [Make vb.net app capable of running on any PC with .net installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350762/make-vb-net-app-capable-of-running-on-any-pc-with-net-installed)
2. [.Net Framework 2 application not working on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024974/net-framework-2-application-not-working-on-windows-10)
3. [Creating Applications for various versions of the .NET Framework](https://www.barcodefaq.com/knowledge-base/multiple-framework-versions/)
4. [< supportedRuntime > element](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element)

Comment: See the table here: [How to: Configure an App to Support .NET Framework 4 or later versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5). It describes the behavior of an application that targets .Net 3.5 with multiple `<supportedRuntime>` elements in machines that have FW 3.5, and/or 4.0 or higher installed. Note that the order of the entries counts and that when you specify the `sku` version, if the installed Framework is a version lower than the app's Target FW, the app fails to run and asks to install an update

Comment: So, the order of the `<supportedRuntime>` entries specifies a preference and the optional version specified by the `sku` attribute changes the behavior when the installed Framework is lower than the app's Target Framework. Also, note that running on a Framework other then the one the Application was built against may have *unexpected* (it reads *expected*) consequences. You may want to target FW 2.0 or 3.5 and run on that.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you. On my Windows 7 (pirate version) was pre-installed [these versions](https://prnt.sc/r3l17k). Then my application should works correclty because is present at least `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>` on *.config* file, but this not happens :-(. Why?

Comment: If i use a feature (eg: [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) in my application) that was introduced on .NET v4.0 and target my application (by "Project > properties" menu or on project creation) to v2.0 for example, i will receive compiler erros saying somethis like "**Task.somemethod()** not available". Then, i need that my target can be 4.0 and my application work fine in possible installed versions 2.0+

Comment: You cannot add references and have dependencies that rely on FW versions higher than the minimum FW version you want to support. If you want your app to support FW 2.0, then set that FW as the minimum version (the Framework you target). You cannot reference `System.Threading.Tasks` (for example) and expect that your executable can run on FW 2.0 or 3.5. Or add NuGet packages that have similar requirements.